# seaborn distplot y axis density value going above 1.0 on few bins

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I am using `seaborn distplot` to plot the density distribution of a column. I assume that y axis is the density and hence each bin should have a height below 1.0. But my `bins` and `kde` curve is going above `1.0`.

Don't know whats wrong

```py
def dist_plot(df,cols=[],bins=None):
    if len(cols) <= 0:
        return
    for c in cols:
        sns.distplot(df[[c]], bins=bins, 
                     hist=True, kde_kws={"label": c},
                     norm_hist=True)
    return
```

```sh
       mean_x    mean_y
0    0.407407  1.454545
1    0.500000  3.555556
2    0.352941  3.062500
3    1.000000  1.950000
4    0.882353  1.562500
5    1.230769  1.285714
6    0.533333  1.357143
7    0.461538  1.642857
8    0.400000  1.571429
9    0.454545  1.600000
10   1.000000  1.818182
11   0.789474  1.681818
12   0.652174  1.551724
13   0.736842  1.300000
14   0.666667  1.923077
15   0.900000  1.611111
16   0.555556  1.615385
17   0.714286  1.307692
18   0.500000  1.333333
19   0.916667  1.875000
20   0.818182  1.210526
21   0.454545  2.000000
22   0.600000  1.625000
23   0.900000  1.714286
24   0.714286  1.333333
25   0.937500  2.066667
26   0.571429  1.666667
27   0.230769  1.900000
28   0.875000  1.888889
29   0.800000  1.818182
30   0.750000  0.909091
31   0.500000  1.900000
32   0.692308  2.666667
33   1.142857  2.142857
34   0.714286  1.333333
35   0.538462  1.777778
36   0.800000  1.400000
37   0.571429  1.142857
38   0.555556  1.500000
39   1.000000  1.545455
40   0.400000  1.000000
41   0.928571  1.000000
42   0.727273  1.857143
43   0.750000  2.071429
44   1.000000  1.285714
45   0.000000  1.055556
46   0.454545  1.333333
47   0.459459  1.608696
48   0.666667  1.148148
49   0.678571  1.200000
50   0.588235  1.869565
51   0.625000  1.437500
52   0.733333  1.000000
53   0.961538  1.931034
54   1.476190  1.551724
55   1.062500  1.560000
56   1.000000  1.363636
57   0.708333  1.466667
58   0.526316  1.833333
59   0.954545  1.500000
60   0.931034  1.235294
61   0.736842  1.421053
62   0.695652  1.083333
63   0.952381  1.130435
64   1.153846  1.500000
65   1.055556  0.875000
66   1.250000  0.941176
67   0.782609  1.550000
68   0.731959  1.519231
69   1.000000  1.384615
70   0.823529  1.527778
71   0.925926  1.523810
72   0.900000  1.687500
73   0.615385  1.071429
74   1.060606  1.333333
75   1.100000  1.030303
76   1.062500  1.080000
77   0.692308  1.666667
78   1.117647  1.227273
79   1.000000  0.846154
80   1.200000  0.818182
81   1.050000  0.954545
82   0.800000  1.111111
83   1.000000  1.125000
84   0.933333  1.454545
85   1.850000  0.947368
86   1.055556  1.166667
87   1.068966  1.333333
88   0.948718  1.466667
89   0.868421  1.468750
90   0.741935  1.571429
91   0.666667  1.454545
92   0.840000  1.421053
93   0.866667  1.296296
94   1.197917  1.414634
95   1.144444  1.564103
96   1.202128  1.456522
97   1.092105  1.239130
98   1.066038  1.272727
99   1.011494  1.121951
100  0.848214  1.378378
101  0.672269  1.282051
102  0.858407  1.180000
103  1.061947  1.355556
104  1.017544  1.169811
105  0.909091  1.369565
106  0.919540  1.228571
107  1.105263  1.172414
108  1.282051  1.529412
109  0.867925  1.320000
110  0.819672  1.309091
111  0.884058  1.086957
112  0.750000  1.346939
113  1.105263  1.342105
114  0.973684  1.387097
115  1.075000  1.032258
116  1.000000  1.375000
117  1.100000  1.258065
118  1.166667  1.333333
119  0.925000  1.181818
120  0.825000  1.000000
121  0.896552  0.851852
122  1.111111  1.150000
123  1.022989  1.452381
124  1.025641  1.142857
125  1.108108  1.352941
126  1.025000  1.250000
127  1.057971  1.066667
128  1.015152  0.794118
129  1.180556  1.107143
130  1.087500  1.243902
131  1.000000  1.108108
132  1.023256  1.171429
133  1.118421  1.111111
134  1.027778  1.257143
135  1.000000  1.107143
136  0.837209  1.133333
137  1.066667  1.185185
138  0.692308  0.926829
139  1.100000  1.259259
140  1.428571  1.360000
141  0.714286  1.200000
142  1.200000  0.894737
143  0.888889  1.133333
144  1.000000  1.160000
145  1.000000  1.269231
146  2.333333  1.080000
147  0.666667  1.500000
148  0.222222  1.058824
149  0.500000  1.333333
150  0.200000  1.400000
151  0.300000  1.529412
152  1.166667  1.058824
153  0.571429  1.636364
154  0.250000  1.846154
155  0.500000  0.857143
156  0.600000  1.083333
157  0.750000  0.916667
158  1.272727  1.000000
159  1.300000  1.421053
160  1.000000  1.214286
161  1.166667  1.230769
162  1.375000  1.071429
163  0.800000  1.545455
164  1.111111  1.533333
165  1.111111  1.071429
166  1.000000  1.368421
167  1.200000  1.000000
168  1.500000  0.933333
169  0.875000  1.529412
170  0.750000  1.300000
171  0.800000  1.461538
172  1.142857  1.000000
173  0.833333  1.250000
174  1.250000  1.200000
175  0.833333  1.142857
176  1.000000  1.350000
177  2.500000  0.833333
178  1.000000  1.272727
179  0.500000  0.666667
```

Below image is the result of above code using this data set.

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: That assumption is wrong. Density can be larger than 1. The integral over the density is exactly one.

Comment: The units on the density axis are a common source of confusion. While kernel density estimation produces a probability distribution, the height of the curve at each point gives a density, not a probability. A probability can be obtained only by integrating the density across a range. The curve is normalized so that the integral over all possible values is 1, meaning that the scale of the density axis depends on the data values. From: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. The CDF should not be greater than 1, but the PDF may be. Think, for example, of the PDF of a Gaussian random variable with mean zero and standard deviation σ:

[guasion probability density function](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/gaufcn.html)

if you make σ very small, then for x=0, the PDF is arbitrarily large!